# exist-db - file:move does not move document

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In eXist 4.7 I am trying to move masses of documents into seperate collections.

I build the new target collection dynamically from information in the document (`@corresp`). So this:

```
 for $doc in collection($globalvar:URIdb)//tei:TEI[@type="exempla"]
 let $source := concat("db/apps/thema/data/",
                        $doc/data(@xml:id),".xml")
 let $target := concat("db/apps/thema/data/",
                        $doc/replace(@corresp,"#",""),
                        "/",
                        $doc/data(@xml:id),".xml")
 return ($source, $target)
```

...returns sequences like the following, which are the correct from/to file paths:

```
db/apps/thema/data/TE001553.xml
db/apps/thema/data/TC0001/TE001553.xml
db/apps/thema/data/TE003403.xml
db/apps/thema/data/TC0001/TE003403.xml
db/apps/thema/data/TE003404.xml
db/apps/thema/data/TC0001/TE003404.xml
```

But using the function `file:move($original as item(), $destination as item()) as xs:boolean`:

```
 for $doc in collection($globalvar:URIdb)//tei:TEI[@type="exempla"]
 let $source := concat("db/apps/thema/data/",
                        $doc/data(@xml:id),".xml")
 let $target := concat("db/apps/thema/data/",
                        $doc/replace(@corresp,"#",""),
                        "/",
                        $doc/data(@xml:id),".xml")
 return file:move($source, $target)
```

...returns `false` i.e. no files are moved.

What am I missing in the from/to paths?

Many thanks.

Comment: It turns out `file:move` can only be for file system documents, not in eXist...which explains why it doesn't work.

Comment: Right. Moving resources within the database is done with the xmldb module: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/index.html?q=xmldb:move